# Is there any way to list the contents of the iPhone/OSX Keychain and their security level?

Tags: macos, ios, backup, iphone

I have a few apps that I purchased from the app store that probably store information in my keychain on OSX and on the iPhone.

Since it's possible for keychain items to be bound to a device (and invalid when restored to a new device) I'd like to know what my application uses.

- So, how can I enumerate through the Keychain on OSX and iPhone/iPad and see what kind of security is being used?
- Can I view the full contents of the keychain?

Comment: I believe the application you are looking for is known as 'Keychain Access', in OS X. In 'Snow Leopard' it is under /Applications/Utilities.

Answer (score 4):

On mac os x, you can view the keychain items by opening the Keychain Access application.

On the iphone, keychain dumper can be used to dump all the keychain items. But it only works on jailbroken phones. To know more on usage of keychain dumper visit - http://www.securitylearn.net/2012/03/27/keychain-dumper-usage-explained/